# Having trouble with C# quadratic equation solver

Tags: c#, rounding

I just wrote my first C# program.

It's a simple piece of code which solves quadratic equations.

It works with some functions (such as -6x2-6x+12) perfectly, while with others, (4x2-20x+25) it exhibits what I suspect are rounding errors.

I'm completely new to C#, and I can't see an problems; would someone be able to help me debug this code?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication {
    class Program {
        static int ObtainInput(string prompt, bool canBeZero) {
            double a = ObtainInput("A? ", false);
            double b = ObtainInput("B? ", true);
            double c = ObtainInput("C? ", true);
            double d, x1, x2;

            while (true) {
                Console.Write(prompt);
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                int result;
                bool success = int.TryParse(input, out result);
                if (success && (canBeZero || result != 0))
                    return result;
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!");
            }

            // Calculating a discriminant
            d = b * b - 4 * a * c;

            if (d == 0) {
                x1 = -b / (2 * a);
                Console.WriteLine("The only solution is x={0}.", x1);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            // If d < 0, no real solutions exist
            else if (d < 0) { 
                Console.WriteLine("There are no real solutions");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            // If d > 0, there are two real solutions 
            else {
                x1 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
                x2 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
                Console.WriteLine("x1={0} and x2={1}.", x1, x2);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In C#, nobody uses gotos. Hell, I knew it existed but the syntax is news to me =o

Comment: Change all of your `int` values (`a, b, c, d`) to `double` and try it again. Things like '(-b / (2 * a))', when `a` and `b` are `int` will do "integer division". That's a seriously bad rounding error.

Comment: @Baboon I had the same reaction when I saw them.

Comment: @Verandaguy, please consider making samples smaller for future questions, i.e. there is no need to show code that reads values, no need for ReadLine calls, no need for extra namespaces. Try to make it small: under 7 lines is awesome, small enough to not have to scroll - ok. The one you've posted (with `goto`???) is a bit too much.

Comment: @Jim Mischel Your asnwer is the right one, technically, but since you put it as a comment, StackOverflow won't let me vote it up or designate it as such. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Baboon et al: Sometimes (rarely)a single `goto` can improve readability. I've used `goto` at least twice this year.

Comment: I've tried to use goto a few times, and always end up thinking better of myself. 

To the OP, why not just use a function call?

Comment: @ScubaSteve largely because I was inexperienced in programming (and by extension structured programming) at the time. This is a 7 year old question.

Comment: Ha. Yeah I guess this was an old question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I just wrote my first C# program.

Awesome. Now would be a great time to not get into bad habits:

```
entA: Console.Write("a?");   
try { a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); }
catch 
{ /*If a=0, the equation isn't quadratic*/
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid input"); 
  goto entA;             
}
```

Problems abound. First off, use `int.TryParse`, rather than putting a try-catch around something that can fail.

Second, the comment does not match the action of the code. The code determines if the result is an integer; the comment says that it checks for zero.

Third, do not use a goto when what you are attempting to represent is a loop.

Fourth, look at all that duplicated code! You have the same code repeated three times with minor variations.

Make yourself a helper method:

```
 static int ObtainInput(string prompt, bool canBeZero)
 {
     while(true) // loop forever!
     {
         Console.Write(prompt);
         string input = Console.ReadLine();
         int result;
         bool success = int.TryParse(input, out result);
         if (success && (canBeZero || result != 0))
             return result;
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid input!");
     }
 }
```

And now your mainline is:

```
int a = ObtainInput("A? ", false);
int b = ObtainInput("B? ", true);
int c = ObtainInput("C? ", true);
```

Your bug though is here:

```
x1 = x2 = -b / (2 * a);
```

You do the arithmetic in *integers*, and *then* convert to doubles. That is, you do the division, round to the nearest integer, and then convert to double. Do it in doubles (or, less likely, in decimals) from the start. It should be:

```
double a = ObtainInput("A? ", false);
double b = ObtainInput("B? ", true);
double c = ObtainInput("C? ", true);
```

That is, a, b, and c should not ever be integers.

Comment: Also he has bug in `x1 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);`

Comment: Does it make sense to use `decimal`s for math like this? Especially since there is no overload of `Math.Sqrt()` for `decimal`.

Comment: @svick: Not much, no. But it's better than ints. :-)

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, sorry, I was unclear. I wasn't replying to your comment, but to the answer, where Eric mentioned decimals.

Comment: @EricLippert But what do I do with d? For some reason, it won't compile when I put double d, int d, or decimal d. (more precisely, VS tells me that the "code is unreachable").

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. I've only got "return" once in the whole program.

Comment: @Verandaguy: Well *somewhere* there is a line of code that cannot be reached. Trace through the logic of the method and see if you can figure out why the line of code that is unreachable cannot be reached.

Comment: That's the thing. The code that can't be found is just the letter b, right after *Calculating a discriminant*. I can't see why that would be unreachable.

Comment: @Verandaguy:  I note that you didn't make the `ObtainInput` method like Eric suggested.  Rather, you made the `ObtainInput` method do a lot of stuff _in addition to_ obtaining input.  Keep ObtainInput small, let it do only one job (obtaining input).  Then perform your calculations in other methods (e.g., `CalculateDiscriminant()`).  (Your code is unreachable b/c the infinite loop only returns from the method, it doesn't break out into code following the loop.  Look up what the `return` keyword does. :) )

Comment: I looked up <code>return</code>, but I've still got no idea what to do.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing integer division when assigning to x1 and x2; (you can just change the 2 to 2.0 to change it to double division and get a double result)

It might also make sense to change your a,b,c, and d values to double which will also get past the problem, and allow people to enter non-int values for the coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

int a, b, c;
int d;

first of all, try to use double instead of int, since 1/3 = 0 using integers.